# could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':shared_preferences' of type org.gradle.api.project

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i am trying to use shared preference in my app and before I even use it, just adding the dependency gives me this error. anyone with any idea? thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem with aapt2-proto and fix it in this way:

in ***project-folder/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties***

change this:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip
```

to this:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

and then in ***project-folder/buil.gradle***

change this:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
```

to this:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
```

and then run this command

```
flutter clean
```

build or run your project, good luck.

Answer (score 5):

In adroid studion Project management section select `Project` >>> `External Libraries` >>> `Flutter Plugins` >>> `shared_preferrences_2.x.x` >>> `build.gradle` and change the gradle version to match the one of your App.

[image]

As reminder you can find the gradle version of your App like following
Android >>> `build.gradle`
[image]

Comment: resolved. wow I can't believe how many hours I've wasted on this, kudos.

Answer (score 5):

**Upgrading gradle** in my current flutter project worked for me:

1. Open another project with the **latest version** of flutter
2. Open **android/build.gradle**
3. Check the **classpath version** of gradle being used. For me it was:

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'

4. Update the classpath in your current project to the same.
5. Open **android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties** in the other project
6. Check the **distributionUrl**. For me it was:

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip

7. Update your current project to use the same one.
8. Re-run your current app.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same issue recently and fixed it by simply deleting the following folders and rebuilding the project.

```
C:\Users\"username"\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache
```

and

```
C:\Users\"username"\.gradle\caches
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing the gradle version in the shared preferences build.gradle file to match with the one in the android folder in the flutter app.