# Getting Flutter FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: flutter, firebase, gradle

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':firebase_auth'.

> Could not load compiled classes for build file 'C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-3.3.19\android\build.gradle' from cache.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':firebase_auth' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':firebase_core'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':firebase_auth' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Comment: Did you try to do `flutter clean` in the terminal/command prompt?

Comment: yes, Still getting the same error

Comment: try to downgrade the auth version

Comment: Refer to this if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65032695

Comment: The answer shared by Mr Sahil can potentially solve your problem, If the version in the answer (6.5 and 4.1.1) do not work, try updating to 

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip` 

and


`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'`

These versions work and i can confirm it as I am using these in a production app with `firebase_auth`.

Comment: flutter clean. flutter pub upgrade and try to run again