# Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. this error started when i run on android device. it is fine while run on chrome

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-android

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':file_picker'.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected lock protocol found
> in lock file. Expected 1, found 0.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':file_picker' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle'] on
> object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':file_picker' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11m 19s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                            693.6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

**your pubspec.yaml package does not match with your gradle version**

> **1.** find which **package**[example: file_picker] does not match with your gradle.
>
> **2.** go to the dependecies[lef side on vscode] **->** direct
> dependecy **->** **package**[example: file_picker]  **->** example
> **->** android **->** **build.gradle** [  example      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.1' ]
>
> **3.** follow **step 2.** **->**  and android **->** gradle **->**
> **wrapper** [exapmle distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip]
>
> **4.** please copy the distributed url from the **step 3**, and paste
> into your project android**->** gradle **->** wrapper
>
> **5.** also paste the example classpath
> 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.1' to your  project andorid **->**
> build.gradle

this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67920804/17971818 helped me