# ould not load compiledclasses for build file 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\firebase_core-1.24.0\android\build.gradle' from cache

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM A032F in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':firebase_core'.
> Could not load compiled classes for build file 'C:\Users\blacksanke\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\firebase_core-1.24.0\android\build.gradle' from cache.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':firebase_core' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':firebase_core' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 24s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62071166/could-not-get-unknown-property-android-for-project-shared-preferences-of-ty